# Configure email server and receive email from internet like gmail/hotmailetc

Tags: email, windows-server-2008-r2, system-administration, server-administration

I want to configure own email server. I have windows server 2008 R2 OS (subscribed from one VPS provider).
My requirement is as below:
1. Create new email addresses as and when required with @mydomain.com
2. Receive emails on these new Email address from outside network sender like Gmail/Hotmail etc
3. Read emails

I have bought one domain with Godaddy. I asked them steps but they confused me with get name from your web hosting where you have OS hosted and get your Name Server name and MX record entry. I couldn't figured out these information.

Can somebody please help me to achieve what I want to do?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you have to configure your domain nameservers.

To do that, you have to [Registering and Editing Your Own Nameservers](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/664/setting-nameservers-for-your-domain-names#registering)

Then, set them going to [GoDaddy's How to set Custom Nameservers](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/664/setting-nameservers-for-your-domain-names)

Once you create and set this, you have to wait up to 24 hours .

After your domain is ready to use, you have to install [a mail server application](https://www.hmailserver.com/documentation/v5.5/?page=system_requirements) on your server.